# Is sklearn support removed?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

Could not import sklearn as well as scikit-learn in my pycharm IDE, almost I have worked with them for a year now. Could not fix the issue. Tried uninstalling and installing sklearn learn again and it install a version 0.0 :(

In all my other virtual environments also I could see sklearn as 0.0 version only (without updating it from anywhere!)

And I could see scikit-learn installed, but could not import as `import scikitlearn`

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: [The description for `sklearn` says](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/): *Use [`scikit-learn`](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/) instead.*

Comment: which package manager are you using?

Comment: @Naveen I am using pip for managing the packages

Answer (score 0):

Was using an older version of PyCharm since there was an issue in the debugging in the latest version. But when I tried the latest version the packages were able to be imported! Not sure what went wrong :/